# How to send messages from one user/installation to another using Parse?

Tags: parse-platform

I am developing an Android app using Parse. Currently, I want to implement an instant messaging system, and I have been reading about ParsePush.

My code right now looks like:

```
ParsePush.sendDataInBackground(post, insQuery, new SendCallback() {
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.d("push", "Request Sent!");
            } else {
                Log.d("push", "Request failure >_<" + e.getMessage() + " *** Code: " + e.getCode());
            }
        }
    });`
```

Is ParsePush the only way of sending messages across users/installations?

I am thinking about extending ParsePushBroadcastReceiver and create my own `onPushReceive()` handler so the pushes can be handled silently like a chat message. Is that recommended? Can I keep the default behaviour (showing up on notification bar and make a sound) for instances where the app is in background?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Push or via some third party service.  Pushes can be configured to not include an alert.  A group of installations can be targeted by pushing to a "channel".  see http://www.parse.com/docs

Comment: I guess I am looking for more of a way to achieve "silent pushes" while keeping the "regular push" in place. I know I can extend the ParsePushBroadcastReceiver and define my own onPushReceive(), so that the push does not appear on notification bar, and it can be handled like a chat message. But how do I keep the regular notification behaviour when the app is in the background? Thanks